# iOS subclassing tableviewcell returns nil

Tags: ios, tableview, subclass, cell, uitableview

I am trying to subclass a UITableViewCell for my table but the cell keeps on returning nil. Anyone know why? Thanks.

**TableView Code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    NSLog(@"Nil = YES");
}

cell.callType = currentCall.currentCallType;

return cell;
}
```

**SubClass Code:**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

    UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;

    label.text = callType;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [label addSubview:myContentView];

}
return self;
}
```

Comment: not sure if its the reason but you shouldnt be calling self.ANYTHING in the init statement.  meaning your self.contentView statement

Comment: @owengerig Considering the superclass instance variables themselves are not documented how else would he do it?

Comment: @Jon are you going off your NSLog or are you getting the nil table cell exception? Because your NSLog is hard coded. Just checking.

Comment: You mean that you have the log `"Nil = YES"`? (If you do, that's normal to go in that branch in the code so nothing unusual here) Or that your dataSource method returns a `nil` cell at the end?

Comment: What do you mean "return nil" ? It you are talking about "Nil = YES" getting printed, this is normal because at the moment the tableview is presented onscreen, there is no cell to dequeue. You should get a dozen "nil" printed, but scrolling through the table should not bring any more.

Comment: This line is unusual: [label addSubview:myContentView]. It should be [myContentView addSubview:label]. I don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: @Jon - if the `NSLog(@"Nil = YES");` is the only indicator the cell is nil, how do you know when it's not nil?  Until there are some cells to dequeue, there will be some nil cells.  Also, looks like a programming error in you subclass code...shouldn't the `[super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]` actually be `[super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]`?

Comment: That's weird cause I copied this from an example and that's the way they wrote it and it worked...